# How to display enums in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in MVC and Entity framework, so I have some problem in my first project. So sorry if my question is to noob  :(

***What I have at this point:***
I have table users(ID, Name, Password, TypeID, StatusID) and I have lookup table for this fields TypeID, StatusID UserTypes and UserStatuses.

Here is some code for more clarity

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [TypeID] [int] NULL,
    [StatusID] [int] NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserStatuses](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](128) NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTypes](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](128) NULL
)
```

In UserStatuses Table I store "active", "Blocked"
and in UserTypes "Admin", "User", "guest"

Values in UserTypes mey change in future so, I don't wont to convert Users.TypeID field in Enum.(this is important for me !)

***What I need:***
How display user friendly values "active", "Blocked" for StatusID and "Admin", "User", "guest" for TypeID field, instead of number editor when I am generating view ?

link to some good article is welcome Smile  :)

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of articles on http://asp.net/ that can guide you through using these frameworks.

In particular, you may want to read [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-(c)) which may help you understand better how to display your data in your view.

Answer (score 1):

EntityFramework allows you to declare what it call it as "Navigational Property" in your POCO entity class. For more information read [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Types-of-Entities.aspx).

So in you case what you can do is to declare one navigation property in your `Users` POCO entity class representing `UserStatuses` and `UserTypes` as shown below:

```
    public class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        // Other properties representing table columns here

        public UserStatus UserStatus { get; set; }
        public UserType UserType { get; set; }
    }

   public class UserStatus
   {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description  { get; set; }
   }
```

Now you can refer UserStatus object corresponding to one User. i.e. in UI you can use user.UserStatus.Description to display the value.